# Gremlin querying with the depth information while traversing

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, janusgraph

I have a use-case where users are in a hierarchy like

**user1** --HAS_CHILD--> **user2**--HAS_CHILD--> **user3** --HAS_CHILD--> **user4**

For the given user I need to get all the cars owned by that user and all the cars owned by the children of that user. With the cars, I need to have the user(owner) as well as the depth of that user from the given user.

Ex. The given user is **user2**, then user3 has depth 1, user4 has depth 2.

I can get the car details and owner information using the following query but how can I get the ***childDepth*** ?.

```
g.V().has("User", "id", "user2")
 .union(
    __.out("OWNS").hasLabel("Car"),
    __.repeat(
       __.out("HAS_CHILD").hasLabel("User")
    ).emit().out("OWNS").hasLabel("Car")
 )
 .project("plateNumber", "owner", "model", "year", "childDepth")
 .by(__.values("plateNumber").fold())
 .by(__.in("OWNS").values("owner").fold())
 .by(__.values("model").fold())
 .by(__.values("year").fold())
 .by(???)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `withSack`:

```
g.withSack(0).V().has("User", "id", "user2")
 .union(
    __.out("OWNS").hasLabel("Car"),
    __.repeat(
         __.sack(sum).by(constant(1))
       .out("HAS_CHILD").hasLabel("User")
    ).emit().out("OWNS").hasLabel("Car")
 )
 .project("plateNumber", "owner", "model", "year", "childDepth")
 .by(__.values("plateNumber").fold())
 .by(__.in("OWNS").values("owner").fold())
 .by(__.values("model").fold())
 .by(__.values("year").fold())
 .by(__.sack())
```